# Declaring static object in java

Tags: java

I have a class consisting of static methods.They need to use an object of another class.

Say

```
class A{
  B obj = new B();

public static void method()
{
  //using obj here
 }
}
```

Is declaring `static B obj = new obj()` the right approach here?

Comment: The fact that `obj` is of class `B` has nothing to do with the fact that `obj` can't be accessed in `method()` here. Your problem is the static reference to an instance field. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Declaring it static works indeed, but we can't tell if it's the right approach without more information about how the code is used, or what the elements mean. If my answer is not sufficient for you to decide, please provide more info so that we can help you decide.

Answer (score 2):

> Is declaring static B obj = new obj() , right approach here?

Yes, if you are using obj inside your static method. And, that's the only way to access obj inside the method.

You can't access class A's instance fields without an object of class A

Answer (score 2):

Just change the declaration like this and you are fine:

```
class A {

    private static B obj = new B();

    public static void method() {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class B {}
```

Comment: IMO, if the OP asks "is this the right approach", it means he might want more than "this will work indeed".

Comment: You are right, but in some cases it requires less text to provide a working example then to discuss it in a theory. Here I thought an example would be sufficient. Sorry, if I failed to hit the target.

Comment: I agree that working examples answering the question are far better than plain text. But my point was that your answer was already in the question, so off-topic. When the OP says *Is declaring static B obj = new obj(), right approach here?*, I believe **he knows how to do so**, and that's not his question.

Comment: Your argumentation seems valid to me. I will try doing it better the next time.

Comment: Well that's only my interpretation after all, maybe the OP didn't know how to do it either, in addition to not knowing whether to do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct.

```
class A{
  static B obj = new B();

public static void method()
{
  // now you can use obj here.
 }
}
```

Comment: IMO, if the OP asks "is this the right" approach, it means he might want more than "this will work".

Comment: @Joffrey But unless the OP provides more information, that question isn't decidable.

Comment: @EJP That's why we can provide more generic information about how to decide, or use comments to ask for more details about this particular use case. "we don't have enough info" is quite different from "yeah it works indeed". I believe your comment here should, in fact, be a comment to the OP's question ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare `obj` as a `static` member, you can't use them in `static` methods...

Comment: I believe the OP already knew that, s/he was asking whether or not declaring it static is the right thing to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is declaring static B obj = new obj() , right approach here?

This solves your problem, indeed (see below). 
**Whether or not it is the right approach depends on the meaning you want to give that field**.

- If the field has a global meaning, and it makes sense that it exists without any instance of the class `A`, then declaring it `static` is the right approach, indeed.
- If the field has a meaning only for an object of class `A` (an *instance* of `A`), then it shouldn't be `static` (hence, be an `instance` field). In this case:

  - either it does not make sense that your static method needs to access this field.
  - or it does not make sense for your method to be static because it is instance-related

---

#### Why static solves the problem:

The `static` keyword sort of means "*what I declare here does not depend on an instance of this class, but only on the class itself*".

This is why a `static` method cannot access an instance field (non-static field). The method can be called via `A.method()` but the field does not exist while no instance `new A()` has been created, so the method can obviously not use it.

If the field is declared `static`, then it can be accessed because it is also independent from instances.

Comment: Thanks for removing my confusion.After reading your answer I can say it is right approach in my case.

Comment: @user3505394 Glad to have helped. Upvote is the accepted way of saying "Thanks" here, but you're welcome ;)